# Exclude only 1 chunk in webpack?

Tags: webpack, sass

I am trying to exclude only **main.js** chunk file from `HTMLWebpackPlugin` but when I do `excludeChunks: ["main"]`, it also excludes the main CSS file which I want to keep. I can do multiple entry points for my scss files and exclude `main` but I don't usually see a lot of people having multiple entry points for scss files so I am wondering if there is another way to achieve it.

My entry config

```
entry: {
    main: ["./src/js/index.js"],
    donate: ["./src/js/donate.js"],
},
```

My plugin config

```
   new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      title: "donate",
      template: "./src/donate.html",
      filename: "./donate.html",
      favicon: "./src/images/logo.png",
      excludeChunks: ["main"], // excludes both js and css files bacause they are main.bundle.js and main.bundle.js
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
      },
    }),
   new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css",
   }),
```